# How to fix Attempt to de-reference a null object in test for Post Callout?

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock

I become an error `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` in my test:

```
public class Token{
public String accessToken{get;set;}    
}

public static String accessTokenBody(){  //our web token (data is in fields)
        Settings__c settings = [SELECT ConsumerKey__c, ClientSecret__c, Username__c, Password__c, SecurityToken__c
                                FROM Settings__c
                                WHERE Name = 'OurSettings'];  
        String consumerKey = settings.ConsumerKey__c;
        String consumerSecret = settings.ClientSecret__c;
        String username = settings.Username__c;
        String password = settings.Password__c + settings.SecurityToken__c;
        String request = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + consumerKey +'&client_secret=' + consumerSecret +
                         '&username=' + username + '&password='+password;
        return request;
    }

public static String GenerateJSON(Type__c t){
//I will send and post it like a record in another org:
    Map<String, String> fieldMap = new Map<String, String>{
                   'Name' => t.Name,
                   'Desc__c' => t.Type_Description__c};    
    String serialized = JSON.serialize(fieldMap);         
    return serialized;
 }

public static HttpRequest httpRequest(String service){
    String requestBody = accessTokenBody();
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(requestBody);
    ourRequest.setMethod(service);
    ourRequest.setEndpoint('https://p21.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token');
    return ourRequest;
}

public static HttpRequest finalHttpRequest(String token, String method, String endpointUrl){
    HttpRequest finalRequest = new HttpRequest();
    finalRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
    finalRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    finalRequest.setHeader('accept','application/json');
    finalRequest.setMethod(method);
    finalRequest.setEndpoint('https://p21.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token' + endpointUrl);
    return finalRequest;
}

public static HttpResponse postCallout(String positionId) {
    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = httpRequest('POST');
    //Error is here: 
    HttpResponse response = ourHttp.send(request);      
    Token objAuthenticationInfo = (Token)JSON.deserialize(response.getbody(), Token.class);

    if(objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN != null){
        Type__c typ = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Type__c WHERE Id =: TypeID];
        HttpRequest finalRequest = finalHttpRequest(objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN, 'POST', '');
        finalRequest.setBody(GenerateJSON(typ));
        HttpResponse finalResponse = ourHttp.send(finalRequest);
        if(finalResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('CREATED:  ' + finalResponse.getBody());
            return finalResponse;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Mock:

```
@isTest
global class AnimalsHttpCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.setBody('{"Name":"ttt"}');
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    return response; 
}
```

}
Coverage is just on my `getAccess()`, `httpRequest()` and 5 first rows of `postCallout()` + last row `return null;`:

```
    @isTest
    private class CalloutTest {

    @isTest
    static void testPostCallout() {      

        public class Token{
            public String token{get;set;}    
        }

        Settings__c settings = new Settings__c(Name = 'OurSettings',
                                               ConsumerKey__c = 'REMOVED',
                                           ClientSecret__c = 'REMOVED',
                                           Username__c = 'mail@mail.com',
                                           SecurityToken__c = 'REMOVED',
                                           Password__c = 'REMOVED');
    insert settings;
    String consumerKey = settings.ConsumerKey__c;
    String consumerSecret = settings.ClientSecret__c;
    String username = settings.Username__c;
    String password = settings.Password__c + settings.SecurityToken__c;
    String request = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + consumerKey +'&client_secret=' + consumerSecret +
                     '&username=' + username + '&password='+password;

    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    String requestBody = CalloutClass.accessTokenBody();
    System.debug('request: ' + request);
    System.debug('request2: ' + requestBody);
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(request);
    ourRequest.setMethod('POST');
    ourRequest.setEndpoint('https://p21.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    Type__c typ = new Type__c(Name = 'ttt');
    insert typ;

    Test.startTest(); 
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AnimalsHttpCalloutMock());
    HttpResponse response = CalloutClass.postCallout(typ.Id);
    //System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: 
    String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
    System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
    String actualValue = response.getBody();
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    String expectedValue = '{"Name":"ttt"}';
    System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
    System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
    Test.stopTest();
    }    
    }
```

Comment: You should consider changing all the sensitive, security-related values I just edited out of your question.

Comment: On which line is the `NullPointerException` thrown? What have you done to try to fix it? This exception is almost always fixable just by tracing the `null` value through your data.

Comment: Thank you) But token data was fake) All is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Your code is designed to return a `null` value given an invalid response, and that's exactly what it's doing.

Your test does this:

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AnimalsHttpCalloutMock());
HttpResponse response = CalloutClass.postCallout(typ.Id);
//System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: 
String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
```

Your mock returns this value when called:

```
response.setBody('{"Name":"ttt"}');
```

And then your `postCallout()` method does this with the mock return value:

```
Token objAuthenticationInfo = (Token)JSON.deserialize(response.getbody(), Token.class);

if(objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN != null){
    <snipped>
}
return null;
```

`postCallout()` is designed to return `null` if it doesn't get a valid `Token` structure back. You supplied a mock that does not return a valid `Token` JSON body, so `postCallout()` returns `null` - as designed.

Your test then tries to dereference that `null` value, throwing an exception.

You need to write a mock class designed for your API. You can't just drop a Trailhead mock class in - as you've seen, it won't work. One approach - not the only approach - is to actually construct a `Token` object in your mock and return as the response body the string resulting from doing `JSON.serialize()` on that object.

Comment: So I need to put in response.setBody our request with token data, right? And just then add to mock (or create another Mock) our obkect's data?

Comment: Your Mock needs to return a value that is representative of the real API's return value so that your code can successfully execute.

Comment: Okey. But when I try to put in `response.setBody()` my token string or `JSON.serialize(my token string)` it write `System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value at [line:1, column:231]` or `System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object` :( How can it "eat" my token?

Comment: Your mock has to return the JSON representation of a `Token` object, not the token string itself. Its return value has to be able to be deserialized as a `Token` object.

Comment: Okay. I call in Mock my Token object. Then I make `String serialized = JSON.serialize(settings); response.setBody(serialized);` And get the same error `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` in the same place. Sorry, I'm just learning)

Comment: I've edited a suggestion at the end of my answer.